# JQuery Accordion Default State

Tags: jquery

I need some help with this accordion. Please see the demo here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/a36RL/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
        $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('slow');    
        $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
    });
    $("div.accordionContent").hide();
});
```

I need to make a little changes in it.

1. I want the first tab down by default.
2. If a tab is already down, and that tab is clicked again, there should not be anything (Currently it slides up and then down again).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the click event on the first button to open the first tab.
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
    if($(this).next().is(":visible")){
        return;
    }

        $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('slow');    
        $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
    });
    $("div.accordionContent").hide();
    $("div.accordionButton:eq(0)").click();
});
```

Working example @:

> http://jsfiddle.net/a36RL/7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a36RL/8/   updated the fiddle when the already expanded div is clicked again it closes...

Comment: But OP wanted it be displayed without the slide if it is already open.. Isn't it?

Comment: Thank you very much 3nigma, however Cybernate solution was exactly I was looking for. However, thanks again.